# search text for strings in between strings android

Tags: java, android, json, regex, string

i have this really long `JSON` text where i have to locate a string of a movie title that is between following:

```
(((((((   .","title":" AND ","type":"   )))))))
```

i have read on other solutions like :

```
   String mydata = json;
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".\",\"title\":\"(.*?)\",\"type\":\"");   
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
               while (matcher.find())
             {
                 testare += (matcher.group(1));
        }
```

and also the way messier:

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList( json.replaceAll("^.*?.\",\"title\":\"", >>"")
                    .split("\",\"type\":\".*?(.\",\"title\":\"|$)"));
            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new
                    ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
            final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listVyn);
            myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

`Json` contains the entire text in the `JSON` as a string.
My problem is that when i search for **Dirty** it recommends movies that contains "Dirty" and i want to search the string and pick out all the titles. But for some reason it seems to loop the first movie name, which is "Dirty" and then ignore the rest. what should i do about this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I might suggest a different approach. If you deserialize the json object to a java object, you'll should find the problem much easier. I.e., instead of working with json, you'd be working with a java object, containing the information from the json. You can do this in a number of ways, for instance using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

Once you've done this, you can use myObject to get text from the object. E.g., myObject.getTitle(). If you then want to use regex on *that* string, that's all good. But I wouldn't use regex on the json.

In order to create MyObject.class, which represents the json, you can use: 
http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com

Comment: Hi and thanks for the fast answer. The Json variable i use is a java String. So i searched through the entire json, got all the text in the json to the String and then trying to search the String. So i think im already working in java, dont i?